# Magento 2 : crontab is not working

Tags: magento2, crontab

I am trying to implementing **cron** job for my module but getting error in `CLI`.

I am using windows operating system.

here is **crontab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="customdesignsubcategories_cron">
    <job name="uploadFile_deletion" instance="vender\module\Cron\UploadFileDeletion" method="execute">
        <schedule>1/2 * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

here is **UploadFileDeletion.php**

```
<?php
namespace vender\module\Cron

class UploadFileDeletion
{
protected $_logger;
public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) 
{
    $this->_logger = $logger;
}
public function execute()
{
    $this->_logger->debug('Cron run successfully');
    return $this;
}
}
```

following commands i fire in CLI

```
php bin/magento cron:run --group="customdesignsubcategories_cron"
```

**Error =>**

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]   Invalid Document
>   Element 'job': The attribute 'instance' is required but missing.
>   Line: 4
>
> Element 'job': The attribute 'method' is required but missing.
>   Line: 4
>
> Element 'schedule': Element content is not allowed, because the type
>   definition is simple.   Line: 5
>
> Element 'schedule': [facet 'minLength'] The value has a length of
>   '0'; this underruns the allowed minimum length of '5'.   Line: 5
>
> Element 'schedule': '' is not a valid value of the list type
>   'scheduleDeclaration'.   Line: 5
>
> Element 'run': This element is not expected. Expected is (
>   config_path ).   Line: 8
>
> cron:run [--group GROUP] [--bootstrap BOOTSTRAP]

Comment: This is another Magento bug where if you're in developer mode, Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem line 164, it'll try to validate the merged crontab.xml to the crontab.xsd schema.... Switch to default or production mode and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your crontab.xml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="customdesignsubcategories_cron">
    <job name="uploadFile_deletion" instance="vender\module\Cron\UploadFileDeletion" method="execute">
        <schedule>*/2 * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

Also, ensure your file is indented with spaces instead of tabs (if not done already)